# Google maps api change StreetView lines wieght

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Im using google maps api v3, on project.
It works fine, but not everything. When is drag the streetview guy (yellow man) and try to drop on the map, the Streetviewlayer is setting, but the lines is so thick.
Is there a way to change these lines weight to a bit smaller or thiner?
Thanks a lot

This is a screenshot to my problem:
http://prntscr.com/f36h5u

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the weight of the lines applying weight (px) option to the appropriate feature like:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
    zoom: 12,
    styles: [
        {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{color: '#00ff00'},{weight: 10}]
        }
    ]
});
```

More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference?hl=es-419

Hope I helped you!

Comment: 0.3 seems to be the lowest possible value by the way

Comment: not bad, but i want these weight change to streetview lines. If i drag the yellow man, and show where can i deploy him. Then highlight the possible street and locations. And thats what i want to chnage.Because in google.maps.com its a nice thin line.